# react-i18next: Global Components

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Since `v11.6.0` it is possible to interpolate tags like `<i/>` and `<strong/>`
like in the following example:

```js
<Trans
  i18nKey="myKey"
  defaults="hello <italic>beautiful</italic> <bold>{{what}}</bold>"
  values={{ what: 'world'}}
  components={{ italic: <i />, bold: <strong /> }}
/>
```

Now I do not want to do this every single time. Lets say my translation file is full of `strong` and `i`-tags.

Is there a way to map some tags to default HTML-Elements? (Like, for example, in the init script of i18n?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such capability to define a global component mapping in `react-i18next`.

By default `Trans` component supports `['br', 'strong', 'i', 'p']` as written in the [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-for-less-than-br-greater-than-and-other-simple-html-elements-in-translations-v-10-4-0).